# How to work with Background tasks in IOS using csharp via Visual Studio on mac

Tags: c#, ios, macos, visual-studio

I'm developing an app where I need to use background tasks on IOS. I want to call a REST-API endpoint every 1 minute. I'm having an issue where the task I have defined is not triggered. I'm using the IOS framework that came in version 13 and schedule a task like this:

`BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Register(PingTaskId, null, task => HandleAppPing(task as BGAppRefreshTask));`

Where the HandleAppPIng is the function to call. I have followed all the steps of changing things in the info.plist file, allowing background tasks and processing, and also allowing the taskid which is a string defined. Apparently it does not trigger the handleAppPing function.

Has anyone had this problem and could share some of your thoughts?

Comment: First, if you want to test to see if your background task code is working, see [Starting and Terminating Tasks During Development](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development). That will confirm whether the basic background task logic is working. That’s the best way to make sure everything is set up correctly. Second, background tasks will not fire “every minute”. The best you can do is to specify `earliestBeginDate`, but the time it fires is at the sole discretion of OS (and certainly won't be every minute).

Comment: If your intent is to inform user/app of significant updates, rather than polling, one would generally have the server push silent `content-available` notifications. Regardless, WWDC 2019 [Advances in App Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707) and WWDC 2020 [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063) videos might be illuminating.

Comment: I do think I'm doing things correct, it might also be that the C# version of the framework has bugs in it, or some config needs to be set differently. I got this to work using SWIFT in xCode. That just will not be good enough because I whole app is written in C# and to be used both for IOS and Android. I just don't get why the event is not called after I schedule the task. Here is the full code https://github.com/sigthor/background.ping